# Why does lambda expression assume char instead of string

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following function using a lambda expression:

```
Func<string, DateTime> GetDateFromFileName
               = fileName => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
                                 .Select(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s.Substring(s.Length - 8, 8), "yyyyMMdd", null));
```

but the compiler complains that a `char` has no `.Length` or `.Substring()`. Why is it deciding that `s` is a `char` and not a `string`? And is there a more elegant way to make the above work than throwing in a couple of `.ToString()`s?

```
Func<string, DateTime> GetDateFromFileName
               = fileName => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
                                 .Select(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s.ToString().Substring(s.ToString().Length - 8, 8), "yyyyMMdd", null));
```

How does linq choose what variable type to make that first variable in a lambda expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetFileNameWithoutExtension` returns a `string` which you are then doing a `.Select` on. This means that you are going to enumerate through the chars in the string as a string is a char array.

Linq will look at the colection that you are using and use the type of the internal objects.

Given your edit you could change it to this

```
Func<string, DateTime> GetDatesFromFileNames
           = fileName =>
{
    String filenamenoext = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName); 
    return DateTime.ParseExact(filenamenoext.Substring(filenamenoext.Length - 8, 8), "yyyyMMdd", null));
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I probably shouldn't be using `.Select` then. Is there a more appropriate option that lets me work on the whole string?

Comment: @Dan I think that it will be easier not to use linq at all

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @DavidPilkington yes sorry that was an error. I want just one date from just one filename. I've gone with a multiline `Func<>`, I don't know if that's bad or not but it seems to me to be cleaner than having an irrelevant private function on the object. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidPilkington `s` (in the `.Substring()`) won't be defined :/

Comment: @Dan yeah sorry about that

Comment: @DavidPilkington thanks ya that's exactly what my `Func<>` looks like now

Answer (score 3):

Well, because `string` is a `IEnumerable<char>` and `Select` will operate on `char`s of the `string`. I.e. you can also do:

```
foreach(var c in "hello") {
    // c is a char
}
```

Do do what you (probably) want just remove unnecessary LINQ `Select`:

```
Func<string, DateTime> GetDatesFromFileNames = fileName => {
    var tmp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    return DateTime.ParseExact(tmp.Substring(tmp.Length - 8, 8), "yyyyMMdd", null);
};
```

It donesn't really make any sense to have `IEnumerable` as return since you most probably have only one date in filename?

Comment: @Dan you're right, fixed (I hope), anyway I think you already got the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading correctly, going by your return value of `Func<string, IEnumerable<DateTime>>` you have some list of files with dates attached:

```
fileA20140101
fileA20140102
fileB20140101
```

And you need to get some result containing:

```
fileA: 01-01-2014
       02-01-2014
fileB: 01-01-2014
```

However, your funtion only takes a single `fileName` even though the name contains `fileNames`. Is it possible that the parameter `string fileName` needs to be `IEnumerable<string> fileNames` instead? This might make more sense looking at the implementation of your function!

**Update based on comment**

So your function returns only a single datetime.

```
static DateTime GetDateFromFileName(string fileName) {
     const string format = "yyyMMdd";
     string withoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
     return DateTime.ParseExact(
            withoutExtension.Substring(withoutExtension.Length - format.Length), 
            format, null);

}

Func<string, DateTime> myFunc = GetDateFromFileName;
```

Comment: So there was another error, it should just be returning a single `DateTime`. My appologies, it was as you suggested earlier, I was trying to refactor it to only work on one `string` and return one `DateTime`. I've edited the question

Comment: thanks, what is the purpose of the `Func` at the end now? Also you have to have a third parameter (e.g. `null`) in `DateTime.ParseExact()`

Comment: @Dan, to remain consistent with your example; if you need to have it in some variable. I changed the code in my answer, thanks